# The Timer Tick isn't triggered despite timer start.

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Timer won't ticket I can work out why, I've included the various sections of code.

```
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
```

Then inside my class (internal sealed)

Declared

```
 private int _timeLeft;
    Timer _countDownTimer = new Timer();
    private int _scriptsLeftCount;
```

Then inside Method

```
_timeLeft = timeToStart;
            _countDownTimer.Tick += CountDownTimer_Tick;
            _countDownTimer.Interval = 60000;
            _countDownTimer.Start();

    private void CountDownTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tick " + _timeLeft);
        if (_timeLeft > 0)
        {
            // Display the new time left 
            // by updating the Time Left label.
            _timeLeft = _timeLeft - 1;
            WriteMessage(_timeLeft + " Minutes" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
            _countDownTimer.Stop();
            Restore();
        }
    }
```

Yet it doesn't seem to do any of the tick. Subsiquently not running restore, any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Did you set _timeleft to a positive value somewhere??

Comment: I set _timeleft to a positive value in a config which is pulled in, I also tried `_countDownTimer.Enabled = true;` neither worked

Comment: And this is a winform app? Despite the Console.WriteLine?

Comment: Yes this is a windows forms app, I just used the Console.WriteLine for the debug... 

`using System.Windows.Forms;`
`using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;`

Comment: Use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint on the Start() call and ensure that the debugger breaks on it so you know for a fact that it is getting called.  Then use Debug > Windows > Threads and make sure that this code is running on the UI thread.  It cannot work when it runs on a worker thread.

Comment: _I set _timeleft to a positive value in a config which is pulled in_ But does it happen in the right order? Set a breakpopint on `_countDownTimer.Start();` and check _timeleft !

Comment: @HansPassant It is running in a worker thread... if this isn't possible how can I get a timer to work in the midst of a background operation?

Comment: These are not details you can leave out of your question.  Nor was that the question you asked.

Comment: @TaW i just created windows form project. I assigned _timeLeft value to 100 and removed WriteMessage and Restore methods from Tick event handler. Also i set interval to something like 1000... And it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: The OP's probem has to do with thing he didn't metion especially mixin the UI and a worker thread..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that the WinForms timer runs in the UI thread, and background workers run in a background thread.

That said, you shouldn't be doing it. A background worker shouldn't need to wait for timed periods; if you have something that happens at timed intervals, you can have a timer in the main thread and start new work items when it fires. If you want to wait for input in a background worker, you can use a blocking I/O call. If it needs to wait for some other item to be complete, use EventWaitHandles (Manual- or AutoResetEvents).

However that being said,

If you want to do something repeatedly, you should just use a loop inside the backgroundworker DoWork() method.

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    int delay = 1000; // 1 second
    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        do something
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

If you need a delay longer than 1 second, your loop will have to change a little to allow you to detect whether or not the worker has been closed:

```
int delay = 1000; // 1 second
    int interval = 60000;
    int elapsed = 0;
    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        elapsed = 0;
        do {
          Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
        while (elapsed < interval && !worker.CancellationPending);
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
```